# How do I remove recent projects from Embarcadero C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

How do I remove recent projects in Embarcadero C++Builder 10.4?

I tried regedit, removing files; all to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean "remove them from the welcome screen list" ?

Answer (score 0):

Either

> `File - Reopen - Properties`

or

> `Tools - Options - User Interface - Reopen Menu`